# ClassCastException (Invoking UiApplication on Application)

Tags: blackberry

I am getting this error

```
Thread [TimerDemo(185)id=307040256] (Suspended (exception ClassCastException))  
UiApplication.getUiApplication() line: 462  
TimerDemoTask$1.run() line: 18  
BackGroundProcess(Application).dispatchInvokeLater(Runnable, Object, int) line: 1456    
BackGroundProcess(Application).doProcessNextMessage(Message) line: 2088 
BackGroundProcess(Application).processNextMessage(Message) line: 1530   
BackGroundProcess(Application).enterEventDispatcher() line: 1371    
TimerDemo.main(String[]) line: 15
```

when I am trying to call a popUpScreen() using,

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication()).pushGlobalScreen(new PanicPopUP(), 0, 0)//Defined in TimerDemoTask class.
```

BackGroundProcess class which extends Application calls TimerDemoTask class which invokes popUpScreen() as above. I tried to cast Application and UiApplication in this way

```
((UiApplication)Application.getApplication()).pushGlobalScreen(new TimerDemoPopupScreen(),0,0);
```

but still getting the same exception.Any idea how to impelement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this in your Timertask demo class..
i think you are not getting the eventlock

```
synchronized (getEventLock()) {

    //with this UiEngine pushGlobal dialogs

    //whenever with the app in background

    UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
    ui.pushGlobalScreen(new TimerDemo(), 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
}
```

like this and see if it solved your issue ....

Comment: I replaced my code as per your advice and it worked. No exception now.Thanks Uttam.